# Some applications in Big Sur do not respect Do not Disturb

Tags: big-sur, do-not-disturb

When I enable DND I have some applications that do not respect it, for example, Viber, MS Teams, MS Outlook, WhatsApp, Transmission, and I'm sure others as well. Messenger, Telegram, Mail and other apps respect it.

To my understanding, each non-Apple application has to implement in their codebase the ability to monitor the Do not Disturb functionality of the OS (like they do with the system's theme - dark or light), but DND is not a newly implemented feature for Big Sur, it exists since for a while now; thus I wonder if there is any way to easily fix that or I have to wait for each app to push an update?

I'm on macOS Big Sur v11.2.2, DND is set to "Always On", on my Catalina MacBook Pro Viber seems to respect DND sound-wise, but still bounces in the dock.

If the issue is on my end, is there any way to kind of "reset" the DND functionality in my machine?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not an issue on your end, most likely.  Many applications aren't coded to respect DND.  The only thing you can do is contact the developers and ask for the feature.  I did this for MS Teams a while ago.

Comment: @fsb, thanks for letting me know! I thought that since it is kind of working in Catalina it should also work in Big Sur or maybe it was an issue on my end. I'll drop a ticket for each app then and fingers crossed!

Comment: DND is about notifications but bouncing on Dock ain’t one. From [documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/receive-pause-or-stop-notifications-mh40609/11.0/mac/11.0): “ Many apps on your Mac use notifications to let you know about events, updates, or changes. Notifications appear briefly in the top-right corner of the desktop or stay there until you close them.”

Comment: DND is only for the notifications that appear in Notification Center. Applications like Teams use their own custom notifications and go around Notification Center.

Comment: downvoting a question that is genuinely asked by many people and there isn't any definitive answer is a kind of a stupid move. DND seems to behave differently between OS versions, as I said, Viber doesn't produce any sounds when DND is enabled in Catalina but it does in my Big Sur machine.